# How to read CLOB column in Oracle DataBase from Java

Tags: java, hibernate, clob

I have a table in Database where datatype of a column(STATUS) is CLOB.I need to read that STATUS

```
create table STATUS_TABLE
(
STATE_ID      number(20,0),
STATUS   clob
)
```

I am trying to read CLOB column as below

```
String getStatus = "SELECT STATUS FROM STATUS_TABLE WHERE STATE_ID="+id;
Query statusResults = session.createSQLQuery(getStatus);
List statusRes = statusResults.list();
if ((statusRes != null) && (statusRes.size() > 0)) {
        oracle.sql.CLOB clobValue = (oracle.sql.CLOB) statusRes.get(0);
        status = clobValue.getSubString(1, (int) clobValue.length());
        log.info("Status->:" + status.toString());
}
```

And getting the error as

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy194 cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB
```

How can i read clob data from DB and convert to String ?

Comment: what data you are trying to store ?? why are you using CLOB ?

Comment: I would think using a PreparedStatement -> resultSet and then use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getClob(int) would be better

Comment: Also your Table says `STATUS` but your SQL says `SELECT STATUS_DESCRIPTION`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the corrected version, and an explanation appears below the code:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT STATUS FROM STATUS_TABLE WHERE STATE_ID = :param1");
query.setInt("param1", id);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List statusRes = query.list();
if (statusRes != null) {
    for (Object object : statusRes) {
        Map row = (Map)object;
        java.sql.Clob clobValue = (java.sql.Clob) row.get("STATUS");
        status = clobValue.getSubString(1, (int) clobValue.length());
        log.info("Status->:" + status.toString());
    }
}
```

Problems I saw with your code:

- You were building a raw query string using concatenation.  This leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection and other bad things.
- For whatever reason you were trying to cast the CLOB to `oracle.sql.CLOB`.  AFAIK JDBC will return a `java.sql.Clob`
- You are performing a native Hibernate query, which will return a list result set whose type is not known at compile time.  Therefore, each element in the list represents one record.